# A4 thesis-like two-column CSS with jQuery citation formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to achieve the following layout based on [this PhD thesis](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~turon/turon-thesis.pdf):

[image]

So far I'm doing this using only CSS, however it won't work if I have multiple citations close to each other as they'll end up overlapping in the second column.

**But what's the best way to go about solving it with jQuery? Here's my plan so far:**

1. See if two or more citations have the same start position
2. Copy them into a div, delete originals
3. Move div to the citation start position
4. Format CSS accordingly

```js
function setNewPositions() {
  var citation = $("cite span");
  
  citation.each(function() {
     console.log("Hello");
  });
}
setNewPositions();
```

```css
.Grid {
  padding-right: 30%;
}

.Grid-cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

q[cite] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  max-width: 20%;
}

q[cite]:before {
  content: attr(data-index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Grid-cell">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi<sup>1</sup> <q data-index="1. " cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q> sequi<sup>2</sup> <q data-index="2. " cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q>      sequi<sup>3</sup> <q data-index="3. " cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q>. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
      magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil
      molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you will likely need a JS-based solution for collision detection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, see a working example here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isneezy/gas7897p/). You can adjust to sit your needs

HTML:

```
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Grid-cell">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi<sup>1</sup> <q data-index="1. " cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q> sequi<sup>2</sup> <q data-index="2. " cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q> sequi<sup>3</sup> <q data-index="3. " cite="http://www.mashable.com/">nesciunt</q>. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
      velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis
      autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cite"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.Grid {
  padding-right: 30%;
}

.Grid-cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

q[cite], .cite {
  left: 75%;
  max-width: 20%;
  top: 30%;
  position: absolute
}

.cite a{
  display: block
}

q[cite]:before {
  content: attr(data-index);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('q[cite]').each(function(){
    $('.cite').append('<a href="'+$(this).attr('cite')+'">'+$(this).data('index')+$(this).text()+'</a>');
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```